# How Do You Determine The Type of Word Automatically

Tags: java, generator, cpu-word

Right now I'm creating a program that generates random sentences based on a text file given by the user. I want to randomly choose words from the text file, and generate a cohesive sentence with them. Basically,  I want to randomly choose a word from the text file and check whether it a noun, verb, adjective, or preposition. Then, using those words, I'll randomly form a sentence. I just can't figure out how to find the type of word. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm also doing this in Java fyi.

Comment: Hi, based on what i understood from your question, you should be using some kind of a dictionary which already contains every word in your text with its type; Then when you read a word, you check its type from this dictionary.

Comment: Yes. I found an online source with around 500k words. The problem is, I don't know how to check the type from the dictionary automatically. How do you suggest I do this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, unless you find a database with build in types